# Exportfs: How to dynamically export a folder?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I'm generating a Ubuntu image that will be deployed on different hosts. All hosts need to export a folder. For example `host0` needs to export `/cluster/host0`, `host1` needs to export `/cluster/host1`.

To do that, all nodes will be nfs-servers and export that folder. However, I don't know how to configure `/etc/exports` since the export depends on the hostname of the node.

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```bsh
#/etc/exports
/cluster/$(hostname) <clients>(<options>)
```

Do you know if this is possible? Otherwise, would you recommend a different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Make it be the other way around? The hosts all export `/cluster/foo` and have the clients mount on different directories?

Comment: @muru I also thought about that but I would like that the content of `/cluster` is only the hostname of the nodes. I could also export some other path such as `/local` and let the others mount it to `/cluster/hostX`. If it is not possible to export dynamic paths then I can do that but I was wondering it my question is solvable.

Comment: The usual solution in this case that I have seen is to append lines to `/etc/exports` (or create files in `/etc/exports.d`)  - see e.g., https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-nfs-server/blob/master/nfs_setup.sh#L12 https://github.com/jsafrane/kubernetes-nfs-example/blob/master/exporter/run_nfs#L22 https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nfs-server-docker/blob/master/templates/docker-entrypoint.sh#L31)